# Github Jekyll Workflow failure

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I tried to add the "Jekyll" workflow to my repository in Github, but every time it runs it is marked as failure.

Here is an error message, I tried to remove Gemfile.lock from exclude (`_config.yml`) but it didn't help... Here is a repository to which I'm trying to add a workflow: https://github.com/igorkowalczyk/blog

```
Build the site in the jekyll/builder container
##[error]Process completed with exit code 23.
Fetching i18n 0.9.5
Installing i18n 0.9.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Fetching sass 3.7.4
Installing sass 3.7.4
Fetching jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Installing jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Using listen 3.2.1
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Fetching kramdown 1.17.0
Installing kramdown 1.17.0
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Fetching rouge 3.22.0
Installing rouge 3.22.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Fetching jekyll 3.8.7
Installing jekyll 3.8.7
Fetching jekyll-feed 0.15.0
Installing jekyll-feed 0.15.0
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
There was an error while trying to write to `/srv/jekyll/Gemfile.lock`. It is
likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 23.
```

[image: Github error]

Comment: Please specify a question for others to answer. It's a bit hard to tell what you are looking for right away and this will turn other users away from your question/post.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the question is; you want to know what's causing the error, and how to stop it from happening, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a solution to make this workflow work correctly and show no further error. The very content of the error message is hard to understand, maybe someone had a similar situation

Comment: A quick google search yielded several posts with the same errors, and potential solutions. As such, I'm interested in knowing what you have tried already.

Comment: I tried that and I didn't find anything and I came here if you want to help me send these links please

Comment: Thanks for your search, i paste full error code and find nothing... [Link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435125/github-jekyll-workflow-issue/63451738#63451738)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a so many attempts to fix the tests, i finnaly find a solution, thanks you [@fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978558/fredrik)*

Here is my workflow file:

```
name: Jekyll

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the site in the jekyll/builder container
      run: |
        docker run \
        -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/srv/jekyll -v ${{ github.workspace }}/_site:/srv/jekyll/_site \
        jekyll/builder:latest /bin/bash -c "chmod a+w /srv/jekyll/Gemfile.lock && chmod 777 /srv/jekyll && jekyll build --future"
```

and my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"
gem "minima", "~> 2.5", ">= 2.5.1"
group :jekyll_plugins do
gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
gem "jekyll-paginate", "~> 1.1"
end
```

* Answer in comment: "[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=There+was+an+error+while+trying+to+write+to+%60%2Fsrv%2Fjekyll%2FGemfile.lock%60.+It+is&rlz=1C1GCEB_enSE865SE865&oq=There+was+an+error+while+trying+to+write+to+%60%2Fsrv%2Fjekyll%2FGemfile.lock%60.+It+is&ie=UTF-8) you have my google search. I literally just took the error and pasted into google."

Comment: Adding "chown jekyll:jekyll /srv/jekyll/Gemfile.lock && chown jekyll:jekyll /srv/jekyll/Gemfile" to the "/bin/bash -c" command fixed this problem for me.